# JSON custom class encode/decode in Python - class or function?

Tags: python, json

I have noticed that most often when I see an example of JSON encoding and decoding a custom class:

- In the encoding direction, a subclass is used with the cls parameter
- In the decoding direction, a function is used with the object-hook parameter

...even in the same example.

Is there a reason that this seems to be preferred?  Why not just be consistent in both directions?

Comment: Code says more than a thousand words: post an example!

Comment: Here's an example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3768895/how-to-make-a-class-json-serializable